# Why js click is not working except first click

Tags: javascript, c#, html, click, font-awesome

I want to change icon with every click. This code is worked But just first click. With every click after the first click, nothing happens. If i delete the if & else the click is work with every click. What is the problem ?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 landscapes sale" style="padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;" data-id="@item.Id">
                    <div class="project-single" data-aos="fade-up">
                        <div class="project-inner project-head">
                            <div class="homes">
                                <!-- homes img -->
                                <div href="single-property-1.html" class="homes-img">
                                    <div class="add-favorite">
                                        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    @if (item.Document == true)
                                    {
                                        <div class="homes-tag button alt featured">Document</div>
                                    }
                                    
                                    <div class="homes-price">$ @String.Format(new CultureInfo("hr-HR"), "{0:# ##0}", item.Price)</div>
                                    <img src="~/EstateImages/@item.MainImage" alt="home-1" class="img-responsive">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- homes content -->
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            }

     <script type="text/javascript">
       let announcements = document.querySelectorAll(".item")
       let favoriteAnnouncementsText = localStorage.getItem("favorites")
       let favoriteAnnouncements;
        if (favoriteAnnouncementsText != null){
            favoriteAnnouncements = favoriteAnnouncementsText.split("-");
        }
       for (let i = 0; i < announcements.length; i++) {
           
            announcements[i].querySelector(".add-favorite i").addEventListener('click', function(e){
                if (this.getAttribute("class") == "fas fa-heart"){
                    announcements[i].querySelector(".add-favorite").innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-heart"></i>'
                }
                else if (this.getAttribute("class") == "far fa-heart"){
                    announcements[i].querySelector(".add-favorite").innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>'
                }
            })

       }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your event handler, you replace the element for which the click handler is defined by setting the `.innerHtml` property of the parent element. The html fragment is parsed and integrated into the DOM but that does not preserve the event handler definitions associated with the original element.

Change your event handler to

```
this.classList.toggle("fas");
this.classList.toggle("far");
```

This toggles both classes on the `i` element with each click which is equivalent to switching between those classes on each click. Other classes (ie. `fa-heart`) are not affected. No modification of the DOM structure is necessary.

Ref:

- [MDN: Web API - classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [MDN: Web API - DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList)

Comment: Thanks. This is worked. But i can't understand one thing. Why my method is not working. What was wrong ?